# Dev environnement for gcc with Docker?

Tags: docker

I would like to create a minimalist dev environment for occasional developers which only need Docker.

The ecosystem would have:

- `code-server` image to run Visual Studio Code
- `gcc` image to build the code
- `git` to push/commit the code
- `ubuntu` with some modifications to run the code

I looked to *docker-in-docker* which could be a solution:

- Docker

  - `code-server`
  - `docker run -it -v ... gcc make`
  - `docker run -it -v ... git git commit ...`
  - `docker run -it -v ... ubuntu ./program`

But it seems perhaps a bit overkill. What would be the proper way to have a full dev environment well separated, that only require Docker to be installed on the host machine (Linux, Windows, MacOS, Chromium)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a `Dockerfile`.

This file specifies a few steps used to build an image.

The first line of the file specifies a base image(in your case, I would use Ubuntu):

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
```

Then, you can e.g. copy files to the image or select commands to run:

```
RUN apt install gcc make
RUN apt install git
```

and so on.

At the end, you may want to specify the program that is run when you start the container

```
CMD /bin/bash
```

Then you can build it with the command `docker build -f Dockerfile -t devenv:latest`. This builds a new image named `devenv:latest` (`latest` is the version) from the file `Dockerfile`.

Then, you can create a container from the file using `docker run devenv:latest`.

If you want to use this container multiple times, you could create it using `docker run -it devenv:latest`

If you want to, you can also use the `code-server` base image instead of `ubuntu:latest`.

Comment: In your answer you have one master image `devenv`. I would like to separate the IDE from the build and the run images. So that's why I am looking for a `docker-in-docker` solution (or a better one)

Comment: Just use 2 images? Create an image/container for the IDE and one for docker...

Comment: yep, but how can I make my IDE container to build using the other container?